# Program for managing "Profiles" (Home, work...)

Tags: search

I'm looking for a program that manage profiles for System settings like Network, Displays, Mouse, Power etc. For example: One profile for work to enable new Proxy Settings, setting Brightness and turn Bluetooth on. Another Profile for home, to enable Wireless, disabling the Proxy settings and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> User and group account administration

this is what I found in the Softwarecenter, maybe this works out for your needs.

mind you: I have never tested or used this, so I can't give advise on how to use or run it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the *best* or *only* way to do this but one option would be to create multiple users.  Say 'User' and 'User-home'.

Each user has his/her own home directory and so can be configured as you wish by making changes to `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` for example.

The problem here is that you probably have data you want to share between both users so in the home Directory of user create a subdirectory called 'Data' and in the home directory and  a symbolic link to it in the home directory of 'User-home'.
`ln -s /home/User/Data /home/User-home/Data`

You will also probably want to change the primary group of 'User-home' to match that of 'User' with `sudo usermod -g User User-home`

In this way you have two users who can access each others files with different settings.  For each user any file in `~/Data` is the same file.